Book identification: Sci-fi with hero with leash - title similar to 'Resurgence' or 'Resurrection'
I am trying to recollect a book (most likely a series). Hope someone can help me with the title.
Following are the things I can remember, I read audiobooks:

Book is pseudo sci-fi.
It has a main character who can bond himself with a leash.
It has a lot of royal houses that compete with each other for superpower beings
These superpowers are contained in an orb/box.
It has a 'Great Mother' character who has the power of telekinesis and possibly has a clone.
Hero goes to multiple universes to reach a level where he can match the power of 'Great Mother.'
The main hero acquires a dog and their bonding is superb.
In the climax of the book/series the hero gets the power and he and his team break into one of the rival royal house's castle.

This is all I can remember, please excuse my English as it is not my first language.
Let me know if you can help me, finding the correct book/series.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

I read it in 2023 - not sure when it was published or the cover as it was audiobook! Thank you

What does "bond himself with a leash" mean?

A long shot, but John Norman's Gor is a book series with royal houses and lots of bondage. The third book in the series has an alien, insect-like queen whom I believe used telepathy to communicate with our hero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gor

@Paulie_D bonding as - 'the wizard bonds with a wand' kind of.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen Thank you for the response - Its similar but not the one which I am looking.

I found it. It's the Great Insurrection Series by David Beers.

Alistair believed in the work. He was the last line of defense against the rebels’ unending war to overthrow the Commonwealth. His legend preceded him – the greatest Titan the corps had ever produced.
Alistair’s mission was simple: catch and kill two rebels. Then they said a few words that forever changed his life.
Alexander’s family had ruled the Commonwealth for ten generations. His 30-years as Emperor had been peaceful, but only because he didn’t tolerate dissent. Now, a Titan had betrayed him.

It was a whip, not a leash!
'Bonding' means similar to wizard-to-wand in Harry Potter series.

Hey, it's great that you figured it out, can you tell us a bit more about it?

Also, we'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Thank you all! @Valorum has added context.

Marked as Answer as well.
